# Sitefinity 4 custom modules: OpenAccess necessary or not

Tags: sitefinity, sitefinity-4

With Sitefinity 4, is it a must to use OpenAccess, is it recommended, or is it just an alternative option?

Answer (score 3):

OpenAccess is the ORM used by Sitefinity, so it is certainly recommended and encouraged. However, if you are developing your own modules, user controls, etc and want to use your own data source you're free to do so. Check out this example on [building a simple hello world module for Sitefinity 4](http://www.sitefinity.com/blogs/joshmorales/posts/11-05-19/creating_page-based_modules_in_sitefinity_4.aspx) that doesn't use openaccess at all.

I hope this is helpful!

Comment: Hi Josh, I would say my main concern is the fact that you then have no control over the code that interacts with the data. If you wanted to improve the performance, would you actually have the ability to do so? As far as I know you can't because the ORM will just keep regenerating the files. We saw this in one implementation with Oracle where Nolics proved to be a problem which was never really acknowledged by Telerik. Bottom line is Telerik had no control over  Nolics so they couldn't work on issues such as "Why Sitefinity was performing so disastrously on Oracle"

Comment: Hi Jacques, The issues with Nolics are a prime example of why Sitefinity 4 moved to OpenAccess. Both are owned by Telerik giving them complete control :) Also, OpenAccess actually provides a lot of control over the code that interacts with the data. Using the [fluent mapping API](http://www.telerik.com/help/openaccess-orm/fluent-mapping-getting-started-fluent-mapping-api.html) to build your model allows tweaking of just about any setting, including mapping custom SQL UDTs. In addition, the built in L2 cache OpenAccess provides can be configured to significantly boost application performance.